# Can I reduce the size of the color key generated by heatmap3?

Tags: r, data-visualization, heatmap

I have been using heatmap3 to generate some figures, but I can't work out how to make the automatically generated color key smaller (more specifically, I want to reduce the height of the key). I have tried adjusting keysize as a variable and it doesn't seem to make a difference if I change the keysize value or omit the variable entirely.

```
heatmap3(mat_data, 
    showRowDendro = FALSE, 
    scale ="row", 
    col = my_palette, 
    margins = c(5,5), 
    labRow = NA, 
    keysize = 0.75)
```

This is how it generates the color key and ideally I'd like it to be about half the height of this one.

cropped screen capture of generated color key

[image: cropped screen capture of generated color key]

Comment: doesn't `keysize = ...` give you a warning?

Comment: @rawr Nope, runs as normal. I had hoped adding it would give me an error that I would then be able to work with to find a solution but it just appears to do nothing.

Comment: what package is this from then? `heatmap3::heatmap3` should give a warning